# Parsing Facebook SDK FBSDKGraphRequest result

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

I want to check, if my current Facebook token (it´s present) still has all needed permissions granted by user.

So I call the graph to retrieve all granted permissions associated with my token:

```
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "permissions"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        var resultDictionary:NSDictionary!

        if (error != nil) {
            println("ERROR = \(error)")
        }
        else {
            resultDictionary = result as! NSDictionary
            println("1: ---- SUCCESS (result) ----")
            println("\(result)")

// this doesn´t work:
//                var test = resultDictionary.objectForKey("permissions")?.objectForKey("data")! ?? nil
//                var count = test.count
//                println("---- test (\(count))")
//                println(test)

        }
    })
```

The result from Facebook is:

```
{
id = 646571222102633;
permissions =     {
    data =         (
                    {
            permission = "user_friends";
            status = granted;
        },
                    {
            permission = "publish_actions";
            status = granted;
        },
                    {
            permission = "public_profile";
            status = granted;
        }
    );
};
}
```

Because there might be no/one/a lot of permissions, I want to iterate through the part of the result under permissions / data.

But I´m not familiar with the conversion of this NSDictionary into something where I can `count` the elements down under and `iterate` through.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "permissions"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        var resultDictionary:NSDictionary!

        if (error != nil) {
            DebugOutput("ERROR = \(error)")
        }
        else {
            resultDictionary = result as! [String: AnyObject]

            println("---- SUCCESS (result) ----")
            println("\(result)")

            var test = resultDictionary.objectForKey("permissions")?.objectForKey("data")! as! [[String:AnyObject]]
            var count = test.count
            println("---- test (\(count))")
            println(test)

        }
    })
```

Thanks a lot to: http://ustwo.github.io/tech-blog/2014/08/01/ios-swift-dictionaries/